# Removing Windows newlines on Linux (sed vs. awk)

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Have some delimited files with improperly placed newline characters in the middle of fields (not line ends), appearing as ^M in Vim. They originate from freebcp (on Centos 6) exports of a MSSQL database. Dumping the data in hex shows \r\n patterns:

```
$ xxd test.txt | grep 0d0a
0000190: 3932 3139 322d 3239 3836 0d0a 0d0a 7c43
```

I can remove them with awk, but am unable to do the same with sed.

This works in awk, removing the line breaks completely:

```
awk 'gsub(/\r/,""){printf $0;next}{print}'
```

But this in sed does not, leaving line feeds in place:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g'
```

where this appears to have no effect:

```
sed -i 's/\r\n//g'
```

Using ^M in the sed expression (ctrl+v, ctrl+m) also does not seem to work.

For this sort of task, sed is easier to grok, but I am working on learning more about both. Am I using sed improperly, or is there a limitation?

Comment: Have you tried with quoting: `sed -e s/"^M"//g` ?

Comment: Works as expected for me, with GNU sed 4.2.1...

Comment: @ephemient - which pattern is working for you? I have the same version of sed.

Comment: `sed 's/\r//g'`, even with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1`.  The second one of course does nothing, because `\n` is not part of the pattern space.

Comment: Does that sed delete the \r\n patterns, or replace them with \n? On my system a replacement occurs, not a removal.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe some versions of `sed` will not recognize `\r` as a character. However, you can use a `bash` feature to work around that limitation:

```
echo $string | sed $'s/\r//'
```

Here, you let `bash` replace '\r' with the actual carriage return character inside the `$'...'` construct before passing that to `sed` as its command. (Assuming you use `bash`; other shells should have a similar construct.)

Comment: This appears to be the case. But I have large text groups to process, ~100MB files. Finding other examples of workarounds in bash. Looking for the one that will work in this situation.

Comment: This seems to the be right path, but in the end, awk appears the be the answer. Its syntax is more complicated, but the regexes I give work as expected (same as in Vim).

Answer (score 71):

You can use the command line tool `dos2unix`

```
dos2unix input
```

Or use the `tr` command:

```
tr -d '\r' <input >output
```

---

Actually, you can do the file-format switching in `vim`:

Method A:

```
:e ++ff=dos
:w ++ff=unix
:e!
```

Method B:

```
:e ++ff=dos
:set ff=unix
:w
```

---

#### EDIT

If you want to delete the `\r\n` sequences in the file, try these commands in `vim`:

```
:e ++ff=unix           " <-- make sure open with UNIX format
:%s/\r\n//g            " <-- remove all \r\n
:w                     " <-- save file
```

Your `awk` solution works fine. Another two `sed` solutions:

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;${g;s/\r\n//g}' input
sed ':A;/\r$/{N;bA};s/\r\n//g' input
```

Comment: dos2unix leaves linefeeds (\n) in place. I need to remove them completely. tr only removes the \r, leaving the same result.

Comment: tr -d '[\r\n]' turns the file in one giant line. It appears to remove the characters individually.

Comment: @MattK Why `dos2unix` doesn't work? Can you post your sample input/output file?

Comment: dos2unix appears to replace \r\n with \n. I need to delete the \r\n patterns, as the file already has Unix line endings, and the Windows pairs are garbage data within the lines.

Comment: 2012-07-26|123456||UserName1|0|2004-03-31 00:00:00.000|N||1|0000000002932f3d|San Diego|CA|United States of America|992192-2986^M
  3 ^M
  4 |CREDIT|2004-03-31 00:00:00.000|2004-03-31 00:00:00.000|31|N|N|N||Y|||0||||0|N|1|1|Y||||||||1||1|||N|2004-05-31 18:21:42.403|DEFAULT|||||||||||N||||Y||||||||

Comment: In vim, or even in plain-old **vi**, you can also remove Ctrl-M's at the ends of lines by typing `:%s/^V^M//`.  The Ctrl-V causes the Ctrl-M to be escaped, so that you can include it in the expression.  I do this in FreeBSD and OSX `vi` all the time.

Comment: It does indeed work as expected in Vim. This work is a regular cron job,and IIRC I can pass the ex command through Vim in a shell script?

Answer (score 10):

`sed -e 's/\r//g' input_file`

This works for me. The difference of **-e** instead of **-i** command.

Also I mentioned that see on different platforms behave differently.
Mine is:`sed --version
This is not GNU sed version 4.0`

Answer (score 7):

Another method

```
awk 1 RS='\r\n' ORS=
```

- set Record Separator to `\r\n`
- set Output Record Separator to empty string
- `1` is always true, and in the absence of an action block `{print}` is used

Answer (score 0):

I had the whole file appears as one line with "^M" symbols instead of new lines.
The only solution that worked for me was inside vi type this command (don't copy & paste)

```
:%s/\r/\r/g
```

then save and exit using 'ZZ'

This command tells Vim to replace each carriage return character (\r, which appears as ^M) with a newline character. The % tells Vim to apply the command to every line in the file.