# Removing CRLF in the middle of a line of a file using sed based on a pattern

Tags: linux, sed

I have a java file in which I have the below line with the `CRLF` at the end of the *Logger*.

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerCRLF
        .getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

What I want to do is to remove the CRLF just when it is after *Logger* in my file and join the line into one line as shown below. This should not affect other CRLFs in my file.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

I tried the below command to do it

```
find . -name *.java -exec sed -i 's/Logger\r\n//g' {} \;
```

but I realized that SED reads one line at a time without trailing newline characters so this is not working. From the *man* page I was able to find few commands such as **N**, **P** and **D** but I could not make it work.

So the question is how can I remove one CRLF based on the preceding pattern in a file?

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680914/2877364)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Windows newlines on Linux (sed vs. awk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680815/removing-windows-newlines-on-linux-sed-vs-awk)

Comment: @cxw, My question is regarding SED command not TR or VIM text editor. In your example -d of Tr will remove all the tokens

Comment: @Vahid can you add expected output for clarity? (for ex: if you want blanks in next line to be removed as well).... also, can you have two consecutive lines ending with `Logger\r\n`? I think this is what you are looking for: `sed '/Logger\r/{N;s/\r\n[[:blank:]]*//}'`

Comment: @Vahid I was looking at the `sed` commands at the bottom of that answer.

Comment: @sundeep I added the expected result for more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat -A ip.txt 
private static final Logger logger = Logger^M$
        .getLogger(MyClass.class);$
$ sed '/Logger\r$/{N;s/\r\n[[:blank:]]*//}' ip.txt | cat -A
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);$
```

- `/Logger\r$/` if line matches this regex

  - `N` add next line to pattern space
  - `s/\r\n[[:blank:]]*//` delete `CRLF` followed by optional blanks
- This won't work if there are consecutive lines with `LoggerCRLF`
- Tested with `GNU sed 4.2.2` syntax might vary with other implementations

Answer (score 0):

Right, you've probably realized that to sed, the definition of a "line" is something that ends in a newline, so you're really dealing with multiple lines that you want to join.

You can concatenate lines using the "tr" (translate) command if it is available:
[How to concatenate multiple lines of output to one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580144/how-to-concatenate-multiple-lines-of-output-to-one-line)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/Logger\r/N;s/\r\s*//' FILE
```