# awk includes carriage return (CR) characters

Tags: bash, awk

I have a textfile with a bunch of data and lines like `SID: 1 - SN: 0123456789` scattered all over the file. All lines are delimited with CR/LF (Windows)
In bash I create an array with unique Serial Numbers:

```
sn=($(cat ./serials |awk '/SN: / { print $3 }' FS=': '|sort -u;))
```

So far so good, but each array member contains a CR at the end:

```
echo "${sn[0]}:test"
```

prints `:test56789` instead of `0123456789:test`

I can fix it with `tr -d '\r'` like this:

```
sn=($(cat ./serials |tr -d '\r'|awk '/SN: / { print $3 }' FS=': '|sort -u;))
```

but I doubt if this is the best approach. Is there a way to remove the CR in the `awk` command?

Comment: You could also use `dos2unix` on the file first, but I can't think of any way to get around having to fix the line endings at some point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove carriage return in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680815/removing-windows-newlines-on-linux-sed-vs-awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to remove the LF in the awk command?

Sure you can have awk like this:

```bash
awk -F ': *' '{sub(/\r$/, "")} /SN: / {print $3}' serials
```

Your complete solution to read `awk` output into a bash array:

```bash
readarray -t sn < <(
awk -F ': ' '{sub(/\r$/, "")} /SN: / {print $3}' serials | sort -u)

# check bash array
declare -p sn
```

Comment: Looks good.... but I need the `FS=': '` to get rid of the space. Didn't know about `readarray` - Thanks!

Comment: ok got it, I have edited awk command to address spaces after `:`

Answer (score 0):

3 approaches of the same idea, tested and working on `mawk`, `gawk`, and `nawk`

```
awk '++_[$!++NF]<--NF' FS='^.* SN: ' OFS= RS='\r?\n'
awk '!_[$!++NF]++<--NF'
awk 'NF>++_[$(NF=NF)]'
```

No risk of decrementing `NF` to negative zone, because the incrementing action precedes it.

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: @RohitGupta : which part of 1 single assignment statement confused you ?

Comment: Your answer is in the review queue because it's too short.  It's not that I am confused.  It is for the sake of future viewers, that you should always explain your answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta : thanks for the heads up. Now it's perfectly deduped, can handle both windows and unix files simultaneously

Comment: I have upvoted it :-)